# Is there a way to get S3 buckets or Google Storage buckets on trial basis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created a new account on `Google Cloud Platform` and opted for a trial service. I was, successfully able to create a multi-node cluster for free and I can use this free service for up to 1 year which is more than enough to test few things on cloud. However, I am looking for some trail service for Cloud buckets like S3 from `AWS` or `Google storage buckets`. Is there a way to get it?

Comment: Yes............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you are looking for a free trial of S3 then when you sign up to a new Amazon account you automatically get there [free tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) for a year.

This gives you 5GB free storage and a few other things.

Answer (score 1):

I’m with GCP Support. Google Cloud offers always free 5gb-month usage for regional buckets. This usage limit is available both during and after the free trial period. https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing